# How to sort in specific order - array prototype(not by value or by name)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wish to sort an array of three strings in a specific order.

book, car and wheel.

I can receive these strings in any order. 
There may be one or more strings - max three

I would like to sort the strings in the following  exact order if one or more strings are received.

wheel, book, car

assume the property name is name...

I tried something like this:

```
myitem.sort((a, b) => {
        if(a.name === 'wheel')
          return 1;
        if(a.name === 'book' && b.name === 'car')
          return 1;

        return -1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an object with the order of the values and their order. With a default value, you could move not specified values to start or end of the array.

```js
var order = { wheel: 1, book: 2, car: 3, default: 1000 },
    array = ['foo', 'car', 'book', 'wheel'];
    
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (order[a] || order.default) - (order[b] || order.default);
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This is correct with the removal of the default sorting. There are no other possible values other than those stated in the question

Answer (score 2):

Since you expect instances (in `myitem`) of these three strings only, you can use `filter` on the ordered array, and test the presence of these input strings with `Set#has`:

```
var result = ['wheel', 'book', 'car'].filter(function (s) { 
    return this.has(s) 
}, new Set(myitem));
```

```js
// Sample data being received
var myitem = ['car', 'wheel'];

var result = ['wheel', 'book', 'car'].filter(function (s) { 
    return this.has(s) 
}, new Set(myitem));

// ordered result
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's probably the better idea, it handles unexpected inputs much more gracefully than a `sort` with the partially defined comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly right. I fixed the formatting, etc. and reversed the signs in the sort function.

Of course, this *only* handles sorting items with those three exact names. If you need to handle other inputs, you'll have to decide what should happen to those.

```js
var myitems = [
  {
    name: "book",
  },
  {
    name: "wheel",
  },
  {
    name: "car",
  },
];


console.log(
  myitems.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.name === "wheel") {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.name === "book" && b.name === "car") {
      return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option: indexOf. Undefined values show at the top of the list, but those don't exist. Probably slower than object with index values, but probably easier to maintain if the order changes, especially of the list gets large.

```js
indexOfSort = (a, b) => {
  const order = [
    "wheel",
    "book",
    "car"
  ];
  return order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b);
}

console.log(
['foo', 'car', 'book', 'wheel'].sort(indexOfSort)
);
```